# How can I manually validate a model in the controller after altering the request using ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In have an application that is written on the top on the ASP.NET MVC 5 framework.

I have a page with two separate forms (one visible and the other hidden when the page is loaded). The first form has a drop down menu, if the user selects the option "ABC", I use javascript do display the second form. But if he/she selects any other option, I hide the second form.

Using javascript, I change the required property for the required field to optional since the form is not visible. (this is done only to the client side only)

Now, since the second form has some required fields at the server side, every time I submit the form, the property `ModelState.IsValid` is always false because the second form has some required field which is not provided.

Somehow, before I validate the form, I need to alter the model by setting the `SecondForm` property to null then validate.

Here is how my `ViewModelCapsule` class look like

```
public class ViewModelCapsule
{
    public FirstFormViewModel FirstForm { get; set; }
    public SecondFormViewModel SecondForm { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to work around this issue by using `TryValidateModel()` method on my controller like so

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(int id, ViewModelCapsule model)
{
    try
    {

        if(model.FirstModel != null && model.FirstModel.Menu1 != "ABC")
        {
            model.SecondModel = null
        }

        if (TryValidateModel(model))
        {
            // Here I am expecting the form to validate since the first form has valid date
            // Do somethig with the request

        }

        return new RedirectAction("Index");

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return Content(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

but for some reason `TryValidateModel(model)` is also returning false. I evaluated the incoming data and `FirstForm` has correct data in all of its properties.

How can I manually validate a model in the controller after altering the request?

Comment: Why not just use ajax to load the form if required (and remove it not)? Not sure what you mean by _I change the required property for the required field to optional _ (how would that be possible? or do you mean remove the relevant `data-*` attributes) - but that does not remove any `[Required]` from the server side

Comment: In any case, view models should not contain data models, and you would be better off creating a view model representing what you want in the view and use conditional `[RequiredIf]` attributes.

Comment: Yes I changed `aria-required` on the client side so I can by pass the client side validation. The problem is at the server side. How can I check `[RequiredIf]` to check for a different property? Why can't I just intercept the request and set the `SecondForm` property to null when it should be null and then ask the framework to validate the form again?

Comment: `aria-required`? Are you not using MVC's client side validation? Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf(..)]` or similar attribute (or if you want to write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: So are you saying here that I can't just intercept the request in the controller and manually call a method that will re-validate the object?

Comment: Not at all, just wondering why your taking this approach.

Comment: I don't think I want to install foolproof for this one thing. It sound acceptable to me. But thank you for pointing out what you did, it is something to consider for a large scale

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it to work now. I had to add this line of code to my controller

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

My controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(int id, ViewModelCapsule model)
{
    try
    {

        if(model.FirstModel != null && model.FirstModel.Menu1 != "ABC")
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            model.SecondModel = null

        }

        if (TryValidateModel(model))
        {
            // Here I am expecting the form to validate since the first form has valid date
            // Do somethig with the request

        }

        return new RedirectAction("Index");

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return Content(exception.Message);
    }
}
```